# i am trying to read a txt based website and it is only reading odd lines

Tags: python, list, readline

```
import urllib.request
mypage=urllib.request.urlopen("http://cryptocode.net/cs8/cities.txt")
def makelist(URL):
    list1=[]
    for line in mypage:
        s=mypage.readline()
```

I want to turn the data on the site into a list. When I type `for line in mypage:
print(line)` it prints them all, but when I try to read it, it only reads every other line.

Comment: did you miss that closing quotes in the actual code or just here. I believe its just here. And then, you aren't putting that `s` into the `list1`. Can you also provide the weblink if it is public ?

Comment: no sorry just a typo.. i type in print s and it only prints odd lines. i will put it into the list once i see it is working correctly

Comment: This is wierd .. my box says, No module named urllib

Comment: yeah everywhere online for me says use urllib2 but mine says that one doesnt exist

Comment: I would really suggest using requests library. I will go look for the reason why my urllib isn't working. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: @Vasif the documentation for Python 2's [**`urllib2`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) says it has been changed for Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that when you are iterating through `mypage` with your for loop, you are actually reading it twice. Lets say you have a webpage with this text:

```
Hello
you
Hello
will
Hello
only
Hello
read
Hello
this
```

When you read it with:

```
for line in mypage:
    s=mypage.readline()
```

`s` will contain the `you will only read this`. This is because, when you iterate through with `for line in mypage` it is like saying, `line = mypage.readline()` (Hence, you only get the even lines). Therefore, the corrected code should be:

```
for line in mypage:
    s = line
```

**EDIT**

You will have to store all your data into `list` (I highly recommend that you use a different variable name as `list` is a type) that is declared outside of the for loop using tuples. Then you can use the method `.sort()` or `sorted()` to sort them alphabetically:

```
        # ...
        finallist.append(cities)
        finallist.append(temp)
        finallist.append(populationAmount)
        # Add this instead of the print statement
        list.append((finallist[0], finallist[1], finallist[2]))
    for s in sorted(list):
        print(s[0] + ",", s[1] + " ", s[2] + " ")
```

Comment: @frank please select an answer if that is all.

Comment: sorry to be a bother im just pretty confused, would i put that using the finallist just before i print?

Comment: @frank see my recent edit. I put the use of `sorted()` into your context.